# Please help me to find $Lim_{x\rightarrow\infty}f(x)$ with help of given facts?

Tags: real-analysis

Let $f : [1, ∞) → R$ be a real valued function such that $f(1) = 1$ and for all $x ∈ R $

$f'(x) = \frac{1}{x^2  +f(x)^2}$

Then $Lim_{x\rightarrow\infty}f(x)$

choose the correct options

(a) exists and it is equal to zero.

(b) does not exist.

(c) exists and lies in the interval $[1, 1 + π/4]$

(d) exists and lies in the interval$ (1 + π/4, ∞).$

My answer : i take $f(x) = x$ then $f(1) = 1$

$f'(x) = \frac{1}{x^2  +x^2}=\frac{1}{2x^2  }$

so my answer  is  option $b)$  and $C)$

Is my approach correct? Any suggestions are welcomed.

Comment: Since b and c are contradictory as most one of them can be true.

Comment: Use the fact that: $f(x)\leq \frac{1}{1+x^2}$ and $f'(x)>0$.

Comment: why did you take f(x)=x . the derivative of the same clearly does not matchtheresult.

Comment: This is the third question you're asking with these ambiguous titles that mean absolutely nothing to anyone except perhaps a key group of people. Could you instead start giving your questions *actual* titles? For example "Assume that $f\colon[1,\infty)\to\Bbb R$ satisfies $f(1)=1$ and $f'(x)=\frac1{x^2+f(x)^2}$. What can we say about $\lim_{x\to\infty}f(x)$?", or something else which is descriptive of the actual question? (Of course providing the source is important, but this can and should be done in the body, not in the title.)

Comment: ok, soory@AsafKaragila next time   i will do better

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$f'(x) \gt 0$ so $f(x)$ is increasing.  This rules out $a$

$f'(x) \lt \frac 1{x^2}$ so for $x \gt 1,\ f(x) \lt 1+\int_1^x\frac {dt}{t^2}= 2-\frac 1x$

$f(x)$ is increasing and bounded above by $2$, so the limit exists.  This rules out $b$.

As $f(x)$ is increasing, $f'(x) \le \frac 1{1+x^2}$ with equality only at $x=1$ so $f(x) \lt 1+\int_1^t \frac {dt}{1+t^2}=1+\frac \pi 4$

This shows the answer is $c$

Comment: thanks for Kind help@Ross

Answer (score 1):

Due to the fact that :
$$f'(x)>0,\  f(x)\leq \frac{1}{x^2+1}.$$
By the N_L formula $$f(x)=\int_{1}^{x}f(t)dt+1,$$
so $$f(x)\leq \tan^{-1}x-\frac{\pi}{4}+1.$$
Here follows the result: (c) is the right answer.